# Scrapy Middleware return Response

Tags: python, scrapy

When using a Scrapy Downloader Middleware, and you don't find what you need. Do you build a `Response` object and return that or return the `response`variable passed in with `process_response`?

I tried the latter but kept getting `response has no attribute selector` when used with FilesPipeline.

```
class CaptchaMiddleware(object):

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    download_path = spider.settings['CAPTCHA_STORE']

    # 1

    captcha_images = parse_xpath(response, CAPTCHA_PATTERN, 'image')
    if captcha_images:
        for url in captcha_images:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            print("Downloading %s" % url)
            download_file(url, os.path.join(download_path, url.split('/')[-1]))

        for image in os.listdir(download_path):
            Image.open(image)

    # 2
    return response
```

If I return at `#1`, the `FilesPipeline` runs properly and download the files but if I return at `#2`, it returns an error `response has no attribute selector`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response):

> process_response(request, response, spider) process_response() should
>   either: return a Response object, return a Request object or raise a
>   IgnoreRequest exception.
>
> If it returns a Response (it could be the same given response, or a
>   brand-new one), that response will continue to be processed with the
>   process_response() of the next middleware in the chain.
>
> If it returns a Request object, the middleware chain is halted and the
>   returned request is rescheduled to be downloaded in the future. This
>   is the same behavior as if a request is returned from
>   process_request().
>
> If it raises an IgnoreRequest exception, the errback function of the
>   request (Request.errback) is called. If no code handles the raised
>   exception, it is ignored and not logged (unlike other exceptions).

Comment: I know that. The problem is after I use ```response.selector.xpath```, the problem with FilePipelines occur where it says response has no object selector. Which is not addressed anywhere in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs at https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#textresponse-objects:

> TextResponse objects adds encoding capabilities to the base Response
>   class, which is meant to be used only for binary data, such as images,
>   sounds or any media file.

Bare `Response` objects do not have a `selector` attribute, `TextResponse` and subclasses do:

```
In [1]: from scrapy.http import Response, TextResponse                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [2]: Response('http://example.org', body=b'<html><body><div>Something</div></body></html>').selector                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6fdd116632d2> in <module>
----> 1 Response('http://example.org', body=b'<html><body><div>Something</div></body></html>').selector

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'selector'

In [3]: TextResponse('http://example.org', body=b'<html><body><div>Something</div></body></html>').selector                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[3]: <Selector xpath=None data='<html><body><div>Something</div></body><'>
```

I don't see a new response being created in the code, but from the beginning of the question ("Do you build a Response object and return that (...)") I suspect the snippet might be incomplete, and the response returned at `#2` could be a manually created `Response`.